# Floating point hash table

Tags: algorithm, floating-point, hashtable

I want to construct lookup table using a floating point value as the key.  When I query the table with a given floating point key, I want it to return the value whose key is closest to the query key.

However I don't know beforehand if the floating point keys are evenly distributed or not.

For example, my table might be:

```
key     value
1.0     "red"
1.25    "blue"
2.0     "green"
```

If I query 1.5, I want to get back "blue".

Is there a way to construct the table so that it has O(n) memory and O(1) lookup?  (That is, a hash table).  There's obviously a O(log(n)) algorithm if I store the key/value pairs sorted, but I'm curious if that bound can be improved.

Comment: Do you know anything about (1) the range of the floating point values, (2) the number of significant digits involved or (3) the minimum allowed distance between two values / any restrictions on number count per range?

Comment: I don't think it's generally possible without very specific constraints. I'd just use a binary search.

Comment: If we're talking about IEEE floats, then they're represented in sign-magnitude order, and you can adapt algorithms for 32-bit (64 for doubles) integers.

Comment: Did you mean "if I query 1.24, I want to get back 'blue'"? You can't do O(1) nearest neighbor searches.

Comment: A hash table does not support nearest neighbor queries, so the reference to O(n) space/O(1) time is not so relevant.

Comment: @Dukeling - I know the range, yes.  I don't need to change the table often relative to the number of times I need to query against it, so even though I don't know the minimum allowed distance between two keys a priori, I don't mind calculating it when I build the table.  It sounds like you're thinking about some sort of discretization of the domain?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat - Sounds interesting.  Care to elaborate?

Comment: @JayLemmon "I know the range" - What's the range? "Some sort of discretization of the domain" - Yes, something like that. It's not so much about calculating the distance, but rather about having some guarantees about the distance to allow for this approach to work without excessive memory usage or running time in 'unlucky' cases (when too many values are too close together).

Comment: @Dukeling - Well any finite domain can be mapped to any other in O(1) without changing the relative ordering of IEEE floating point numbers, so without loss of generality let's say the domain is [0,1].

Comment: What I mean is that you can write an (e.g.) Java method `static int intKey(float f) { int i = Float.floatToRawIntBits(f); return i ^ ((i >> 30) >>> 1); }` that converts floats to ints efficiently in an order-preserving manner. Then you can use tries and related structures like van Emde Boas trees. There's no one good data structure for successor queries, so you'll have to experiment a bit if you want the best performance.

Comment: (If the keys are nonnegative, then you can do away with the bit hacks converting sign-magnitude to one's complement and just return `i`.)

Comment: If you ever decide to implement van Emde Boas trees and use it for this, please come back and edit the question to report your results. I'd be incredibly interested in whether they are actually useful for any real-life scenario

Comment: Why a hash table? Why not e.g. a binary tree?

Comment: That’s a good point about signed-magnitude representation of a float. With that, you could do this: Interpret the bits of the float as a signed magnitude int, then convert it to a twos complement int. Ascending numbers from the two’s complement int will correspond to monotonically increasing floats. It’s important to note this may break if the float is a denormal (when they get very close to zero). You can think of these ints as strings of ones and zeroes in lexigraphic order. From here, you can use a data structure called a Trie.

Comment: For English strings a Trie might be a tree of degree 26, but for binary strings it’s just a binary tree.  The existence of each node (or not) records the existence of a bit string so-far. This tree can be stored in an array of bits (1 bit for the 1st level, 2 for the 2nd, 4 for the 3rd, ect.), each bit being the existence of that node or not. Then, if you are traversing the tree for a given floating point value and run out of child nodes (no exact match), then if you wanted to visit a 1 but had to visit a 0, then visit a 1 whenever it’s available thereafter until you hit a leaf node;

Comment: and similarly if you wanted a 0 but there was only a 1 take 0s if possible thereafter. For a 32-bit float this structure is going to take up 512 MB (a 64-bit double would be more space than you’ll ever have on your hard drive). However, if you know things about the range of your exponent, sign bit, and mantissa you can shave down your integer representation of the number to be say 12 bits, then your Trie will only occupy 512 cache-friendly bytes. I’m not sure how practical this all is, but it is one way you could use the signed-magnitude ordering.

Comment: @Apriori Subnormals behave fine with respect to sign-magnitude ordering.

Comment: @David Eisenstat, thank you, that is good to know.

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore the fact that your key is a floating-point number as it really doesn't effect the answer. The answer would be the same if your input was a 32-bit (equivalent to float) or 64-bit (equivalent to double) integer. And, I believe the answer is 'no'.

In order to find the nearest neighbor you need the keys to be sorted. When you have a 32-bit or 64-bit key (it could be helpful to clarify which) that means that you really have no choice but to have a sorted data structure (tree? heap? sorted array?) which you do an O(log(n)) search in.

It's easy to get constant-time access to a specific entry, but getting constant-time access to the nearest neighbor to a specific entry either requires a lookup table with 4 billion entries (for floats) or magic.